# meteor publish composite does not

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I have problems when I try use `meteor-publish-composite`. I see this page https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite and I execute the following code in my meteor project:

```
meteor add reywood:publish-composite
```

I create publish-composite function like this:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Categories } from '../../../../both/collections/administration/category.collection';
import { Structures } from '../../../../both/collections/administration/structure.collection';

//Meteor.publish('categories', () => Categories.find());

Meteor.publishComposite('categoriesWithStructures', {
    find: () => {
        return Categories.collection.find();
    },
    children: [{
        find:(category) => {
            console.log(category);
            return Structures.collection.find({_id: category.structure});
        }
    }]
});
```

But when I initialize the project, in the console I see the message:

```
Property 'publishComposite' does not exist on type 'typeof Meteor'
```

In the `.meteor/packages` file the meteor module is added

```
angular2-compilers
accounts-password
msavin:mongol
reywood:publish-composite
```

My meteor project use `Angular2`.

I will appreciate any help. Regards.

Comment: Is this code running on the server? `.publishComposite()` won't be available on the client.

Comment: Yes, is running on the server

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

My solution looks like
`Meteor["publishComposite"] (...)`
instead of 
`Meteor.publishComposite (...)`

I'm also using typescript for meteor, and I think that its not bet combo (yet).